# Service START_REDELIVER_INTENT retrieves intent but the intent extras are lost

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I am new to android and I am trying to work with Service. To ensure that a service restarts when application is closed and previous intent is received, we write the return statement in onStartCommand function as: return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT.

I am getting the intent but not the Intent extras. Below is the code sample:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
    // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
    // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
    // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.

    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
            Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   // Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
    // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job

    if (null != intent) {
        if(intent.hasExtra("IP")){
            Log.d(TAG, "intent has IP");
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "NO IP");
        }
        if(intent.hasExtra("Topic")){
            Log.d(TAG, "intent has Topic as well");
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "NO TOPIC");
        }
        Log.d("anant", "intent is NOT null");
    }else{
        Log.d("anant", "intent is null");
    }

    Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.arg1 = startId;
    mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
    return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Server_IP = intent.getExtras().getString("IP");
    Topic = intent.getExtras().getString("Topic");
    appPointer = intent.getExtras().getLong("appPointer");

    appID_appPointer.put(Topic, appPointer);
    return null;
}
```

The output is:
NO IP
NO TOPIC
intent is NOT null

The IP and TOPIC variables are put into the intent from another file. They work properly when I run the program for the first time, the extras are received and things turn out as expected. Only when the application is closed and the service restarts, so I find the intent NOT null, but the extras missing. I have searched a lot on the net but could not find anything. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and show your `startService()` call where you are providing the `Intent` that has these extras.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I am also facing same issue.